# How to fix "incorrect su password" in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

With Ansible I am trying to copy a file from one host to another host. I accomplish this using the `synchronize` module and use the `delegate_to`. However, I believe that this is the root of my problems.

```
- hosts: hosts       
  tasks:

  - name: Synchronization using rsync protocol (pull)
    synchronize:
      mode: pull
      src: /tmp/file.tar
      dest: /tmp
    delegate_to: 10.x.x.1
    become_user: root
    become_method: su
    become: yes
```

My code to get the root password

```
- name: Set root password for host
  set_fact:
    ansible_become_password: password
```

My inventory file containing the hosts:

```
[hosts]
 10.x.x.2
```

Now i'm facing the following error:

> fatal: [hosts]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Incorrect su password"}

Playbook:

```
- name: Fetch root password for host from CA PAM
  shell: ./grabPassword.ksh
  args:
        chdir: /home/virgil
  register: password
  delegate_to: "{{ delegate_host }}"
  become_user: "{{ root_user }}"
  become_method: su


- debug:
    msg: "{{ password.stdout }}"


- name: Set root password for host
  set_fact:
    ansible_become_password: "{{ password.stdout }}"


- name: Copying tar file over (Never existed)
  synchronize: 
    src: /tmp/emcgrab_Linux_v4.8.3.tar 
    dest: /tmp
  delegate_to: "{{ delegate_host }}"
  register: test
  become: yes
```

Comment: To get the obvious out of the way, have you checked that you are in fact using the correct password? Have you `ssh`ed into the server and manually run `su - root`?

Comment: @CalumHalpin Hello, yes I have made sure that I am using the right password. I also have made sure that I have tested the ```su - root``` on the actual host and it worked.

Comment: Where are you running the step that sets the password? You're showing it as a separate block?

Comment: @Calum Hapin I run it at the beginning on the playbook

Comment: Could you post the whole playbook rather than the two pieces separately?

Comment: @CalumHalpin Alright I updated the info with my playbook. At the top it grabs the root password of the target host (FYI)

Comment: I see you're setting become parameters on the first task. Are you also setting them for the play? You can override the parameters per task, you don't need to use `set_fact`. Is the error you're getting definitely caused by the `synchronize` task? Could you post the full output?

Comment: @CalumHalpin No, I didn’t set it for the whole playbook, the only time I use ‘’’become: yes’’’ is when I use that synchronize module. And that’s the only error message I am getting. “Incorrect su password”

Comment: That may be the only error you got but what point did you get it at? You set `become: yes` on the `sychronize` task but `become_method: su` on the `shell` task.

Comment: @CalumHalpin It runs fine until it hits the “Copying tar file over(Never existed)”. Then it gives the fatal error. “Incorrect su password”. I hope I answered your question.

Comment: @CalumHalpin Morning, I tried a different solution last night and realized that the issue seems to stem from the ```delegate_to``` module. Though when I tried to enter the correct password for the delegate host instead of the inventory host, it still passed back the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have not set the become password in the command line or configuration.